# How to extract value from a string in shell script?

Tags: shell, sh

I have this environment variable

```
echo $DT_CUSTOM_PROP
```

returns

```
APPCODE=IK22 ENVIRONMENT=DEV APPLICATION=xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx ANOTHERKEY=ANOTHERVALUE
```

How can I get `APPLICATION` from it?

So that if I do `echo $APPLICATION` I get `xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx`

Comment: what does `echo "$DT_CUSTOM_PROP"` return? (ie. are the spaces in your original output really spaces?)

Comment: The same: `APPCODE=IK22 ENVIRONMENT=DEV APPLICATION=xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx ANOTHERKEY=ANOTHERVALUE
`

Comment: Is `DT_CUSTOM_PROP` set by something you trust? If so, it looks like you could do: `APPLICATION=$(eval $DT_CUSTOM_PROP; echo $APPLICATION)` or even just `eval $DT_CUSTOM_PROP`

Comment: yes. let me check

Comment: That works. Thanks! What I want to get only the application?

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```bash
DT_CUSTOM_PROP='APPCODE=IK22 ENVIRONMENT=DEV APPLICATION=xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx ANOTHERKEY=ANOTHERVALUE'
```

You can do it with [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) in a 2-step process:

```bash
tmp=${DT_CUSTOM_PROP#*APPLICATION=}
application=${tmp%% *}    # ==> xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx
```

Or with bash regex matching

```bash
if [[ $DT_CUSTOM_PROP =~ "APPLICATION="([^[:blank:]]+) ]]; then
    application=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
else
    application="not found"
fi
```